# How do I rename my rhel filesystem name?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have 2 identical servers, both installed with RHEL7.6 . During the installation part I made a mistake of didn't provide the hostname on server 1 during the GUI installation, I then change the hostname using hostnamectl command on server 1.

As for server 2, I provide the correct hostname during the GUI installation. However I notice that both server have different naming in the filesystem when I entered DF command.

[Server 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Dfv.png)

[Server 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdF3K.png)

Any idea how I could remove the hostname from server 2?

Comment: Are you sure its worth the hassle and risk of breaking the system? What is the output of "vgs;lvs" - This will tell us the group volume and logical volume and you can then use lvrename and vgrename to rename the systems. Then you need to update /etc/fstab and hope nothing is broken. And you need to do all this while the volume is unmounted for added fun.

Answer (score 0):

use lvrename:

```
lvrename /dev/vgMain/lvTest lvAnotherTest
  Renamed "lvTest" to "lvAnotherTest" in volume group "vgMain"
```

You'll need to update `/etc/fstab` with the new name if you're **not** using UUID's for disk/partition naming.